# NodeJS: Https Request Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443

Tags: node.js, http, https

So I want to load an image from an external URL.

```
var https = require('node:https');

export const loadImageFromUrl = (url: string) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      https.request(url, function (response: any) {
        resolve(response);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
};
```

For example, the image is from `https://en.pimg.jp/054/313/779/1/54313779.jpg`. When I run the code, it gives me this error:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443

This is weird, the URL is not from my local computer, why does `https` search from my local address?

Comment: Yes, same thing, same error

Comment: try : `var https = require('http');`

Comment: Tried http, there is another error something like 'https' protocol is not supported.

Comment: Tried with options, it gives `Error: socket hang up`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/practical-sinoussi-wvkzug?selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A4%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A4%7D%5D&file=%2Findex.js Here's the updated code you can use. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code. It should work.

You can have a look at the live demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/practical-sinoussi-wvkzug?selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A4%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A4%7D%5D&file=%2Findex.js)

```
const https = require("https");
const { URL } = require("url");

const loadImageFromUrl = (url) => {
  const urlParams = new URL(url);
  const hostname = urlParams.hostname;
  const path = urlParams.pathname;

  const options = {
    hostname: hostname,
    port: 443,
    path: path,
    method: "GET",
  };

  const request = https.request(options, (res) => {
    res.on("data", (data) => {
      console.log(`response data: ${data}`);
    });
  });

  request.on("error", (error) => {
    console.error(`Error on Get Request --> ${error}`);
  });
  request.end();
};

loadImageFromUrl("https://en.pimg.jp/054/313/779/1/54313779.jpg");
```